# google analytics page load sample zero

Tags: google-analytics

I'm using Google Analytics to track Page Load Times, but the most visited page has an Avg. Page Load Time of Zero. It also has a Page Load Sample of Zero. How is this possible given that it gets more traffic than the other pages and the other pages have non-zero values? How do I get the Avg. Page Load Time and the Page Load Sample to not be zero?
[Page Load Times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKtlb.png)

Answer (score 0):

The Page Load Sample is zero, so the report has dismissed all views to that particular page, so all other measurements are zeroed out either.

I'm not quite sure but I think sampling is by user/client id, so if the same user has viewed the page a lot of times the pageviews might be sampled out completely.

In any case, you should try to increase the [site speed sample rate](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#siteSpeedSampleRate). Per default it's one percent, and on a site with few visitors that might not be enough to get a representative sample. There is a cap (at max. 10 000 measurements or 1%, whatever happens first) but for a smaller site you should use a bigger sample.

Comment: The site speed sample rate is already 100. That did not fix the issue.